# Segmentation/Clustering on pixel intensity algorithm

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

I'm currently implementing a image processing algorithm that needs segments of the image, clustered by their mean intensity.

I have a working function using the OpenCV K-Means clustering algorithm, however it is slow in performance. I was wondering if other segmenting algorithms exist that are faster.

I found other segmentation algorithms, but most are for detecting objects. I need seperation based on intensity.

Any ideas?

Comment: A very fast pixel clustering implementation based on k-means is available here: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post17_divquant_clustering/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [pyrMeanShiftFiltering](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrmean#void%20pyrMeanShiftFiltering%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20sp,%20double%20sr,%20int%20maxLevel,%20TermCriteria%20termcrit%29) function? It is not particularly fast, so it may not be faster than what you currently have, but you can try it and find out. [Here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/meanshift_segmentation.cpp) is the OpenCV sample using `pyrMeanShiftFiltering`. This function operates on color for clustering, which may not be what you need, but you can take a look at how it is implemented [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/segmentation.cpp); it might give you some more ideas to try.

Comment: the link needs a username and password to see the content.

Comment: @JorgeAguilar Thanks! The OpenCV team moved their code to GitHub and apparently ROS locked their repo down. Hopefully, that will help you out!

Answer (score 0):

A fast and efficient graph-based segmentation algorithm can be found [here](http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/).
This algorithm is described in the paper of 
Pedro F. Felzenszwalb and Daniel P. Huttenlocher, [Efficient Graph-Based Image Segmentation](http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf),
IJCV 2004.

It works fast and capable of extracting regions with roughly similar intensities. I used it once or twice in the past and it works quite well.